# value not coming properly from web services usin soap friends

Tags: java, web-services

I am getting the value from web service using soap but the value is in html tag format and some special characters are showing up. I am not getting the correct value

The actual value is:

```
 BODY="&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;WIDOWS: 2; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: separate; FONT: medium 'Times New Roman'; WHITE-SPACE: normal; ORPHANS: 2; LETTER-SPACING: normal; COLOR: rgb(0,0,0); WORD-SPACING: 0px; -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px; -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 
0px&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;Apple-style-span&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span 
class=&amp;quot;Apple-style-span&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;LINE-HEIGHT: 11pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 11pt&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;MsoNormal&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Sage may not have set investors&amp;amp;#8217; collective pulse racing in the past, but we believe that the market is missing a trick on this solid growth and potential takeout story. Not only are there revenue and margin opportunities in emerging/&amp;lt;?xml:namespace prefix = st1 /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;st1:country-region w:st=&amp;quot;on&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;st1:place w:st=&amp;quot;on&amp;quot;&amp;gt;US&amp;lt;/st1:place&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/st1:country-region&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;Apple-converted-space&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;healthcare markets, the stock also looks very attractive on the Quest&amp;amp;#8482; LBO framework. With 28% upside to our&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;Apple-converted-space&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://www.csquest.com/QUEST?clpg=ART&amp;amp;amp;id=1092&amp;amp;amp;clid=&amp;amp;amp;pg=SEN&amp;amp;amp;spl=&amp;amp;amp;cid=0802165&amp;quot;&amp;gt;adjusted Quest&amp;amp;#8482; per share of 326p&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;Apple-converted-space&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;and upgrades likely to come through post the October numbers, Sage is certainly worth a look.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;LINE-HEIGHT: 11pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 11pt&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;MsoNormal&amp;quot;&amp;gt;The company&amp;amp;#8217;s longevity (two decades), huge customer base, strong distribution capabilities/customer support model, internationally recognised brands and highly cash generative business (with 65% subscription revenue) makes it an ideal candidate for M&amp;amp;amp;A. And the business continues to grow. There are plenty of opportunities in emerging markets (where Sage&amp;amp;#8217;s presence is small), and then there&amp;amp;#8217;s the high-growth US healthcare market where Sage is well positioned due to its industry-accredited products and focus on the move towards web and mobile technologies. Yet, we believe there&amp;amp;#8217;s nothing in the share price to reflect all these attractive M&amp;amp;amp;A characteristics.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;LINE-HEIGHT: 11pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 11pt&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;MsoNormal&amp;quot;&amp;gt;On Quest&amp;amp;#8482; the stock looks marginally expensive, but as the&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;Apple-converted-space&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://www.csquest.com/QUEST?clpg=ART&amp;amp;amp;id=&amp;amp;amp;clid=&amp;amp;amp;pg=VAL&amp;amp;amp;spl=&amp;amp;amp;cid=0802165&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Valuation page&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;Apple-converted-space&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;shows, Sage has normally traded at a premium to the default value per share. Today&amp;amp;#8217;s 14&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;%&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;Apple-converted-space&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;downside is, in historic terms, at the bottom of the range (&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://www.csquest.com/QUEST?clpg=ART&amp;amp;amp;id=197&amp;amp;amp;clid=&amp;amp;amp;pg=CHR&amp;amp;amp;spl=&amp;amp;amp;cid=0802165&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Charting page&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;). However, given the company&amp;amp;#8217;s demonstrable ability to beat the returns fade (impressive CFROA performance), we believe it&amp;amp;#8217;s appropriate to delay the returns fade for two years &amp;amp;#8211; generating an adjusted Quest&amp;amp;#8482; value per share of 326p&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span&amp;gt;(28% upside to Friday&amp;amp;#8217;s close).&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;LINE-HEIGHT: 11pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 11pt&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;MsoNormal&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Given it&amp;amp;#8217;s attractiveness to potential bidders (helped by an LBO FCF yield of 11%), we&amp;amp;#8217;ve run Sage through the Quest&amp;amp;#8482; LBO model. At a 25% bid premium (319p), assuming 50/50 debt/equity and at &amp;amp;#8216;normal&amp;amp;#8217; trading multiple, Quest&amp;amp;#8482; sees a healthy three-year IRR of 25%. The &amp;amp;#8216;normal&amp;amp;#8217; valuation excludes both the valuation highs of the TMT bubble and the lows of the recession. As shown in Figure 1, the IRR&amp;amp;#8217;s key sensitivity is the exit multiple. At the current depressed multiple (8.4x EV/EBITDA; 2.3x EV/sales; 12.5x P/E), IRR falls to a mere 4%.&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://10.113.73.61/QUEST?PCF=MOBILE&amp;amp;amp;clpg=ARTICLE&amp;amp;amp;pg=SUM&amp;amp;amp;cid=0802165&amp;quot;&amp;gt;http://10.113.73.61/QUEST?PCF=MOBILE&amp;amp;amp;clpg=ARTICLE&amp;amp;amp;pg=SUM&amp;amp;amp;cid=0802165&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;" IS_PROTECTED="0" PDF_NAME="" REFERENCE_CITN_ARTICLE_ID="23220" ISNEWARTICLE="1" HYPERLINK="/PATH/23220.pdf"><SUMMARY>Sage may not have set investors’ collective pulse racing in the past, but we believe that the market is missing a trick on this solid growth.
Under-appreciated LBO candidate. Buy.</SUMMARY><AUTHORS/></ARTICLE><ASSOCIATED_COMPANIES ARTICLE_ID="23220"><COMPANY ID="1724" SHRT_NAME="Sage" NAME="Sage Group (The) PLC" SHARE_PRICE="242.0" ADJ_QUEST_VAL="45.0" CURRENCY="p       " ARTICLE_COMPANY_ORDER="1" ARTICLE_COMPANY_TYPE="ICV"/></ASSOCIATED_COMPANIES><COMPANIES_WITH_AUTH context="COMPANIES"><COMPANY NAME="Sage"/></COMPANIES_WITH_AUTH></ROOT>
</getDataResult></getDataResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope
>
```

The value I get is:

```
 BODY="&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;WIDOWS: 2; TEXT-TRANSFORM: \
none; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: separate; FONT: medium 'Times New Roman'; WHITE-SPACE: normal;
 ORPHANS: 2; LETTER-SPACING: normal; COLOR: rgb(0,0,0); WORD-SPACING: 0px; 
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px; -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 
0px&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;Apple-style-span&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span 
class=&amp;quot;Apple-style-span&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE: 12px&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;TFTFont&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;MARGIN-LEFT: 36pt&amp;quot; 
class=&amp;quot;MsoNormal&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font face=&amp;quot;Arial&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 10pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font size=&amp;quot;1&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font size=&amp;quot;1&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;230512107-01062007&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font color=&amp;quot;#000000&amp;quot; size=&amp;quot;2&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt&amp;quot; lang=&amp;quot;EN-US&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font size=&amp;quot;2&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: 'Wingdings 2'; COLOR: rgb(212,46,18); FONT-SIZE: 12pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;#161;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;480350618-03012007&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font color=&amp;quot;#000000&amp;quot; size=&amp;quot;2&amp;quot; face=&amp;quot;Arial&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/font&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/font&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/font&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/font&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/font&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/font&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: gray; FONT-SIZE: 7pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;font face=&amp;quot;Arial&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&a
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to talk to the web service provider. Either that, or you have somehow mansged to request a html formatted response rather than a soap response.